# Docker : Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified

Tags: docker

Am new to docker, started learning today.
I am using Windows Terminal to run the docker command.
I ran this command - docker run postgres:10.20
Got an error stating -
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

```
   You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
   connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.

   See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

Can anybody help me on how to add password to that command in the Terminal, Apart from running an environment to add password in docker-compose.yaml.

Am beginner to stack overflow as well and was not allowed to add image to provide a reference. Assistance needed

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres:10.20
```

Here is the documentation for setting environment variables for `docker run`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

Comment: Thank you so much @Marcos, Now able to run the PostgreSQL successfully and it has started as well.